# Does Paramiko support non-secure telnet and ftp instead of just SSH and SFTP?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm looking at existing python code that heavily uses Paramiko to do SSH and FTP. I need to allow the same code to work with some hosts that do not support a secure connection and over which I have no control.

Is there a quick and easy way to do it via Paramiko, or do I need to step back, create some abstraction that supports both paramiko and Python's FTP libraries, and refactor the code to use this abstraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, paramiko has no support for telnet or ftp -- you're indeed better off using a higher-level abstraction and implementing it twice, with paramiko and without it (with the ftplib and telnetlib modules of the Python standard library).